# Como modificar un campo de un adoquery desde otro formulario

Tags: delphi, pascal, freepascal, lazarus

Tengo un formulario que tiene un `TAdoQuery` llamado `qyPatientContact` y quiero al campo `qyPatientContactNote` modificarlo desde otro formulario.

Estoy intentando con esto:

```
TfmMdPatientContacts.qyPatientContactNote.AsString:=memo.Text;
```

Donde `TfmMdPatientContacts` es el nombre de formulario donde esta el `TAdoQuery`.

El formulario de donde lo estoy llamando se llama `TfmMdPatientContactsAddNote`

Comment: Independientemente de la respuesta, estaría bien que cuando explicas el problema (que aquí parece claro) añadieras datos significativos de lo que estás preguntando. En este caso si obtienes un error sería necesario saber cual es. Algo de códifo de como está definido ese formulario también sería útil.

Answer (score 0):

Lo normal es que `TfmMdPatientContacts` sea el nombre de la clase del formulario (ya que empieza por una **T**) y que el nombre del formulario sea `fmMdPatientContacts`.

Si es así el cídigo correcto sería:

```
fmMdPatientContacts.qyPatientContactNote.AsString := memo.Text;
```

Además deberás añadir al **USES** de la unit donde está este código, el nombre de la unit donde está definido el formulario `fmMdPatientContacts`.

Si no es así, con la información que das es difícil saber qué puede estar pasando.

Comment: Creo que conviene aclarar que esto será el caso si se utiliza la auto-creación de formularios, o al menos, la variable que, por defecto, declara el Delphi a la hora de añadir el nuevo formulario dentro del proyecto, pero no en todos los casos.

Comment: @jachguate Correcto, pero como bien hemos dicho, sin más detalles tampoco podemos "afinar" más la respuesta.